# Can the Vitali Convergence Theorem hold even where the sequence of functions isn't integrable?

Tags: measure-theory, solution-verification, lebesgue-integral

$\newcommand{\d}{\,\mathrm{d}}$I here use Royden's definitions of equiintegrability, and tightness:

> A family of measurable functions $\{f_n\}_{n\in\Bbb N}:X\to\Bbb R$, where $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ is a measure space, is said to be equiintegrable if: $$\forall\varepsilon\gt0,\,\exists\delta\gt0:\forall A\in\mathcal{A},\,\forall n,\,\mu(A)\lt\delta\implies\int_A|f_n|\d\mu\lt\varepsilon$$
> The family is said to be tight if: $$\forall\varepsilon\gt0,\,\exists E\in\mathcal{A},\,\mu(E)\lt\infty:\forall n,\,\int_{X\setminus E}|f_n|\d\mu\lt\varepsilon$$

With that out of the way, and paraphrasing the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_convergence_theorem) to account for my different nomenclature (I use Royden's so as to be able to follow my own notes as I type this), I find that Wikipedia formally requires the family $\{f_n\}$ to be a subset of $\mathcal{L}^p(X)$, yet the proof I have here never requires the $f_n$ to be integrable; for the sake of rigour, I would dearly like to know if it is required that $\{f_n\}\subset\mathcal{L}^p(X)$ for $\lim_{n\to\infty}\|f-f_n\|_{\mathcal{L}^p}=0$.

Vitali's Convergence Theorem, Finite Case (one possible statement - I have seen many slight variants):

> Let $\{f_n:n\in\Bbb N\}\subset\mathcal{L}^p(X)$ where $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ is a finite measure space. Suppose $(f_n)$ has a pointwise limit $f$; if $\{f_n\}$ is an equiintegrable family, then $f\in\mathcal{L}^p$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_Xf_n\d\mu=\int_Xf\d\mu$.

And "my" proof (a combination of Royden's less general work and what I have scrounged from other stack posts):

> As this proof immediately generalises if $p\neq1$, w.l.o.g take $p=1$. As $\mu(X)\lt\infty$, Egorov's theorem ensures that $\forall\delta\gt0,\,\exists E\in\mathcal{A}:\mu(E)\lt\delta,\,(f_n)|_{X\setminus E}\rightrightarrows f|_{X\setminus E}$. The $\mu$-finiteness of $X$ also gives that $X\setminus E$ is of finite measure, hence, by uniform convergence: $$\forall\varepsilon\gt0,\,\exists\delta\gt0,\,\int_{X\setminus E}|f-f_n|\d\mu\lt\frac{\varepsilon}{3}$$
> Where $E$ is as before and all $n\gt N$ are suitably large, and $\delta$ is chosen suitably small. Fatou's Lemma combined with the equiintegrability of $\{f_n\}$ shows that, if $\delta$ is suitably small: $$\int_E|f|\d\mu=\int_E\liminf_{n\to\infty}|f_n|\d\mu\le\liminf_{n\to\infty}\int_E|f_n|\d\mu\lt\frac{\varepsilon}{3}$$Since equiintegrability requires that if $\mu(E)\lt\delta,\int_E|f_n|\d\mu$ may be made as small as desired, with the same $\delta$ for all $n$.
> Taking $\delta$ to be the smaller of the two used above, and for $n$ as large as before, and $E$ as before, then one has:$$\begin{align}\forall\varepsilon\gt0,\,\forall n\gt N:\int_X|f-f_n|\d\mu&\le\int_E|f-f_n|\d\mu+\int_{X\setminus E}|f-f_n|\d\mu\\&\le\int_E|f|\d\mu+\int_E|f_n|\d\mu+\int_{X\setminus E}|f-f_n|\d\mu\\&\lt\frac{\varepsilon}{3}+\frac{\varepsilon}{3}+\frac{\varepsilon}{3}=\varepsilon\end{align}$$And therefore $f_n$ converges to $f$ in $\mathcal{L}^p$ norm.

One deduces that $f\in\mathcal{L}^p(X)$ by a similar argument, that necessitates the integrability of $\{f_n\}$. However, I am fairly sure that one has convergence in $\mathcal{L}^p$ norm anyway, regardless of whether or not $\{f_n\}\subset\mathcal{L}^p$, since Egorov's theorem doesn't require integrability, and I don't believe any of my steps did either.

Using the above definition of tightness, if one requires that $\{f_n\}$ is also tight then the requirement that $\mu(X)\lt\infty$ may be dropped; moreover, in *this* case, I believe one has that $f$ is $p$-integrable and that $f_n\to f$ in norm regardless of whether or not $f_n$ are themselves $p$-integrable. I will add the proof I have if this statement requires expanding.

The question:

The formal statements require $\{f_n\}$ to be integrable; I believe that to get the convergence-in-norm conclusion, one may drop this requirement, and if one replaces it with $\{f_n\}$ must be tight, one gets all conclusions independent of the integrability of each $f_n$. Is this right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to have $\{|f_n|^p\}$ equi-integrable in the statement of the theorem. Using many symbols makes your proof hard to read. The proof can be written without any $\exists$ or $\forall$.

I wrote a proof for $L^p$ myself to check, and I agree that you don't need the hypothesis $f_n \in L^p(X, \mu)$ to deduce that $\lVert f_n - f \rVert_{L^p} \to 0$.

The equiintegrability of $|f_n|^p$ and the finiteness of the measure space do imply that $f_n \in L^p(X, \mu)$, and therefore that $f \in L^p(X, \mu)$.

The tightness hypothesis for $\{|f_n|^p\}$ is just there to reduce to the finite measure case, so the $f_n \in L^p$ hypothesis is redundant here too.